# creating menu in Android

Tags: android

I am new to Android application development.I want to develop a simple android application which contains menus.Is there any source code on internet.Can anybody tell me how should i pursue

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: Can you specify what kind of menu's you mean? Full screen menu's, the menu you see when you press the 'menu' button?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Everything you need to know is in the [Android Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

What it comes down to - and I'm just copying relevant parts from the Android Dev guide - is creating an XML menu resource, e.g. this one, and saving it as `game_menu.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game" />
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

And then inflating it within your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

When an item is clicked, you can do several actions:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.new_game:
        newGame();
        return true;
    case R.id.help:
        showHelp();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: do u have any source code of menu creation in android..If yes..Could you please upload..

Comment: My answer above includes all the source code necessary to create an options menu. You will find everything else in the developers guide I linked to at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: There are 3 fundamental types of the menu:


1. Option menu and Action bar
2. Context Menu and Contexual action mode
3. Popup menu

Answer (score 3):

**XML CODE:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_new"          
          android:title="New" />

     <item android:id="@+id/menu_about"         
          android:title="About" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_help"         
          android:title="Help" />
</menu>
```

**Main Code:**

```
package com.menuexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MenuSample extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);         

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menus, menu);
        return true;
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.menu_about:
            Toast.makeText(MenuSample.this, "You Clicked About", 3000).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_help:
            Toast.makeText(MenuSample.this, "You Clicked Help", 3000).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_new:
            Toast.makeText(MenuSample.this, "You Clicked New", 3000).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers have covered the traditional menu used in android. Their is another option you can use if you are looking for an alternative

https://github.com/AnshulBansal/Android-Pulley-Menu

Pulley menu is an alternate to the traditional Menu which allows user to select any option for an activity intuitively. The menu is revealed by dragging the screen downwards and in that gesture user can also select any of the options.