# Where to put main menu's XML?

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

## Where do you put main_menu.xml in project?

I am trying to make a action bar.
If main_menu.xml is the xml for the action bar,
**Where do I store the action bar's xml?**
**NOTE: Not Duplicate! Yes, there are examples of action bars, but I am just wondering, ***where do I put the XML file?***

Comment: you need to include in activity.

Comment: I do have one, although where do I put it? Like where do I store it on my device?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating menu in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180105/creating-menu-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @RedLight here is the tow way define action bar one is directly dynamically add action bar inside your activity or other way is If you want to customise  your action bar then you can use toolbar and in action bar dynamically, following was the example you can see.

1. Directly set Actiobar or Title (Ad  code inside your activity on Crate)

For the dynamic action bar you need to define theame of activity with action bar like following.

```
<activity
            android:name=".ActivitySplash"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
```

And inside your activity :

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home"); // Define here your actionbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // If you want to create home or back button inside actionbar
```

2. And for second type define your toolbar inside your activity top and define them as not action bar like foollowing,

   ```
       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />
       </RelativeLayout>
   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
   ```

Theme like

```
<activity
            android:name=".ActivitySplash"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And finally set toolbar to action bar dynamically

```
Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar); 
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

For the menu you have to create menu directory inside "res" directory and put inside that directory and following code in activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
   switch (item.getItemId()) 
   {
     case R.id.search:
      //your code here
        return true;
     default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

Comment: Uhh... Thanks, But Where Do I Put the Main Menu's XML? That is my question.

Comment: I already wrote about it, Inside res directory create one another directory name is menu directory and put it inside of menu directory .

Answer (score 2):

In the `res` directory inside a `menu` directory. Something like

`res/menu/some_menu.xml`

If you don't have this directory, and you are using Android Studio you can right click the `res` directory, then click `new`, then `Android Resource Directory`.

[image: New resource directory window]

In the pop-up window write `menu` as Directory name, and select `menu` for Resource type, and finally click `OK`.

Inside this directory you can put all your `menu.xml` files.

PS: I have to answer this again, I have the same question and the accepted answer was more about how to do toolbars than where to put a menu xml file.